# Is there any limit on the size of the CAD file, say RVT file that Forge Viewer can display?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

We have large Revit files ranging from 10MB to 200MB. The forge viewer seems to take time but load them. The problem arises with our own algorithms which get properties inside the viewable once it is loaded in Forge Viewer. I was wondering if Forge Viewer itself has any limit on the size of the metadata or CAD files which it could display. Also, the getProperties call on the viewer object has any limitations on bigger metadata?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither the Viewer nor our Derivative Service (model translation) themselves has any hard limits on the physical size/complexity of the models being processed.

The real boundaries however lie with the browser - different browser on different devices have various memory limits for each tab and they will crash if the model gets too large, and the processing efficiency of the Derivative Service may vary depending on the platform workloads, causing translation jobs to get timed out if the model is too large and complex (which is an ongoing issue that our Engineering is looking to mitigate).